# How to efficiently join two files using Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a dictionary file which is very similar to an actual dictionary. That is it stores words and an index for each word. The number of words is quite large, let's say 2 million words. I have another file which stores a the top words for a bunch of documents. That is, each line in the second file has a key which refers to a document (document name) follows by 10 values which are the indexes of the words in that document. I would like to efficiently merge these two files in order to obtain the top words for each document using Hadoop.

One naive solution is to output the index of the words as the key in the mapper and the value can be either the document name or the actual word. But because there are many words, the number of reducers will be huge and the solution may not be scalable.

Another solution is to buffer the dictionary file in mapper and do the join in the mapper, but it requires lots of memory in the mapper side. Is there a better solution to do that (without being worried about the memory issue?)

Comment: Are you considering only map reduce, or any others like hive or hbase.

Comment: Just map-reduce. IS Hive any different? because it gets translated into map-reduce jobs.

Comment: yes, but it takes care of map reduce, and you need not woory. you think in terms of joins similar to sql. Your best bet would be - as you already have docuemnt with list of indexes, the inxedes need to be replaces with words. So a map which reads each line in 2nd files will take document and then for each line, you can look up for index to get the word from second table. The above look up needs to be performed which gives you O(1) retrieval time.Your format is similar to [forward index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing#The_forward_index). Try studying the algorithms

Comment: You're referring to the second solution I proposed, right? My only concern about this approach is that because the dictionary file can be huge I run into some memory problem?

Comment: Well, as your case is not a typical join scenario(because of multiple indexes for document), loading a file into mapper, should not be a problem, as thats what it is designed to do(run in parellel). You can use joins in mapreduce. If the two data sets are large, you have to perform join at reducer stage. It takes memory, but thats the bet, if you need only mapreduce for implementation.

Comment: I got a little bit about your question. Do the word and its index have one to one relationship? Or not? Can you give an example?